# Update one table from another doing some math

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres 9.6.6, latest Ubuntu LTS.

I have a big main table and a small one, who receiving data from external sensors. Each record of the small one have the record id of the big one.

```
Table_1                       Table_2
  id  temp0  temp0temp1         temp1   Tab1_Id
   1    3       0                 35        2
   2    5       0                 15        3
   3    8       0                 75        1
   4    9       0                 45        4
   5    3       0                   .some
   6    8       0
   7    2       0
   .tens of thousand...
```

I'am looking for an efficient solution to update each record of the big one, doing some math, ie:

```
Table 1 (after)
  id  temp0  temp0temp1
   1    3      78
   2    5      40
   3    8      23
   4    9      54
   5    3       0
   6    8       0
   7    2       0
```

Something similar to:

```
UPDATE Table_1 
SET temp0temp1 = Table_1.temp0 + (SELECT temp1 
                                  FROM Table_2 
                                  WHERE table_2.Tab1_Id = Table_1.Id)...
```

Thanks
Perez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `update ... from`

```
UPDATE Table_1 t1
  SET temp0temp1 = t1.temp0 + t2.temp1
  from Table_2 t2 
  WHERE t2.Tab1_Id = t1.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html). On each insert of table 1 run a procedure that will update table 2 with desired calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1
set temp0temp1 = temp0 + temp1
from Table_1 t1 join
  Table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.Tab1_Id
```

Comment: Do **not** repeat the table to be updated in the FROM clause.